# Code First entity framework and foreign keys

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Imagine I have a database created by code first that looks like this.

```
Movie (table)
ID int PK
MoveiName nvarchar(100)

Actor (table)
ID int PK
ActorName nvarchar(100)
Movie_ID int FK
```

These are the models I would have used, obviously not exactly like this but you'll get my point.

```
class Movie
{  
    int ID{get;set;}
    string MovieName {get;set;}
    List<Actor> Actors {get;set}
}

class Actor
{
    int ID{get;set}
    string Actorname{get;set}
    Movie Movie{get;set;}
    int Move_ID{get;set;}
}
```

Database first enables me to query the movie from an actor but also lets me set the forgien key property of the actor to update the database. I cant do this in code first because the foreign key isnt in the model only the object. I prefer not to get the Movie object and set the property, if i know the id of my movie I'd rather just set the foreign key without the call to get the movie.

Make sense? lol

I want to use codefirst and entity migrations but i want the same ability as database first to set a foreign key on an object.

Cheers for the help :-D

Comment: "I cant do this in code first because the foreign key isn't in the model". It's code first - add it to your model! Some developers don't like foreign keys and some do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx

Comment: I'm aware you can add it to your model, but then the migrations creates duplicate keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First change your code to this

```
public class Movie
{  
   int ID{ get; set; }
   string MovieName {get; set; }
   List<Actor> Actors {get; set; }
}

 public class Actor
 {
    int ID{get;set}
    string ActorName{ get; set }
    Movie Movie{ get; set; }
    int MovieID{ get; set; }
 }
```

By [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx) EF will know that `MovieID` is the foreign key to `Movie`

Then change `Actor` code to this:

```
public class Actor
{
    int ID{get;set}
    string ActorName{ get; set; }
    Movie Movies{ get; set; }
}
```

Actors appear in many movies. Movies have many actors....  :-)

But going back to your one-to-many where an actor only appears in one movie - if you really want the foreign key to be `Move_ID` then add a [data annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591583#relationships):

```
[ForeignKey("Move_ID")]
Movie Movie{ get; set; }
```

Or configure it using [`FluentAPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>()
               .HasRequired(c => c.Movie)
               .WithMany(d => d.Actors)
               .HasForeignKey(c => c.Move_ID);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this isnt a really scenerio and that if I want a movie database you are right. Actors can be in many films I like the extra thought. The only difference then is the _? I've started using orchard recently and the _ I think it's convetion there.

Comment: No, you'd also have to put the 'i' back into the 'Move' part to turn it into 'MovieID'. Alternatively you could use 'ID' everywhere. It's all in the getting started pages I linked to. Please go have a read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Comment: being a sensitive soul I maybe reading a little annoyance in your replies that may or may not exist. However your answers are spot on. I added the foreign key back on my model without the _ and it worked brilliantly. Good man.